# kubernetes architecture for microservices application - suggestions

Tags: java, python, docker, kubernetes

I have been asked to create a system which has different functionalities. Assume service 1, service 2 and service 3. I need to run these services per hour to do something. 
To make the system of those services I need: database, web interface for seeing the result of the process, caching and etc.
This is what I have thought about so far:

- I need kubernetes to orchestrate my services which are packaged as docker containers. I will deploy mySql to save my data and I can use Redis cache for caching.
- My service are written by python scripts and Java and need to interact with each other through APIs.
- I think I can use AWS EKS for my kubernetes cluster

---

this is what I need to know:

- how to deploy python or Java applications and connect them to each other and also connect them to a database service
- I also need to know how to schedule the application to run per hour so I can see the results in the web interface.

**Please shoot any ideas or questions you have**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use kubedns or similar  to allow you to use service names between containers. Run a timed loop in your applications

Comment: @cricket_007 can't I use a tool like Jenkins to schedule my apps, the fact is that I can run my apps in the Jenkins too but not sure how they will interact then

Answer (score 1):

For python/java applications, create docker images for both applications. If these application run forever to serve traffic then deploy them as `deployments`.If you need to have only cron like functionality, deploy as  `Job` in kubernetes.

To make services accessible, create services as `selector` for applications, so these services can route traffic to specific applications.

Database or cache should be exposed as `service endpoints` so your applications are environment independent.